How to tell what kind of event a SCI represents?
I am trying to understand the ACPI event programming model.
According to the ACPI 6.5 spec, SCI (System Control Interrupt) will be raised for two kinds of events: fixed event and general-purpose event.
Below are some quote from the ACPI 6.5 spec Section 5.6.1 Table 5.185.

PM1x_STS bits raise ﬁxed ACPI events. While a PM1x_STS bit is set, if the matching PM1x_EN bit is set, the ACPI SCI event is raised.


GPEx_STS bits raise general-purpose events. While a GPEx_STS bit is set, if the matching GPEx_EN bit is set, then the general-purpose SCI event is raised.

My question is,
When a SCI is received by the OSPM (a subsystem of the OS for power management and platform configuration), how could OSPM know which kind of event the SCI represents?
I think this question is important because it will affects how the OSPM decides how to handle the event. For fixed event, it will handle by itself. For general-purpose event, it may call some ASL control method. Unfortunately, it seems the ACPI spec mentions nothing about it.
ADD 1
Let me put my question another way:
When OSPM sees a SCI, it can check the PM1x_STS register or the GPEx_STS register to see what triggered the SCI. But how could the OSPM know which register to check? Or does it check both?
Thanks.

I do not understand what the issue is. Have you read what you cited? It answers your question. The OSPM reads respective registers and decides what to do. ACPICA, for instance, has a list of subscribers for the GPEs, so OSPM may react on them. Yet ASL may also give the way of handling GPEs, there are two or three ways (I don’t remember by heart) how to describe it there. The most confusing one might be a GPE device that has some grey areas in the specifications).

@0andriy Thanks for reply. I do believe the OSPM should reads respective registers. Could you check my ADD 1 part? Meantime, I will re-read the ACPI spec. Thanks.

The answer to your ADD 1 is that it has to read both.  That's true with any piece of hardware that has multiple interrupt sources  -- it is the responsibility of the interrupt handler to determine the exact cause of the interrupt.

@TimRoberts Thanks. That's so natural. I wish the ACPI spec could have mentioned it since it is already so lengthy...

@TimRoberts If you can turn your comment into an answer, I would be more than happy to mark it as the answer.

The answer to your ADD 1 is that it has to read both. That's true with any piece of hardware that has multiple interrupt sources -- it is the responsibility of the interrupt handler to determine the exact cause of the interrupt.
